# Unhandled exception calling CertCreateCertificateChainEngine function

Tags: c, visual-c++, cryptoapi

I'm following this tutorial from Microsoft [Example C Program: Creating a Certificate Chain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382042(v=vs.85).aspx)

But I get Unhandled exception calling CertCreateCertificateChainEngine function at the following block

```
if(CertCreateCertificateChainEngine(
     &ChainConfig,
     &hChainEngine)) {

    printf("A chain engine has been created.\n");
}
else {

    MyHandleError("The engine creation function failed.");
}
```

Exception message is:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7535F61A (crypt32.dll) in capi_verify.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCCCCCCD0.
```

Here is how the variables are defined:

```
HCERTCHAINENGINE         hChainEngine = NULL;
CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG ChainConfig;
```

and the ChainConfig struct is initialized as:

```
ChainConfig.cbSize = sizeof(CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG);
ChainConfig.hRestrictedRoot= NULL ;
ChainConfig.hRestrictedTrust= NULL ;
ChainConfig.hRestrictedOther= NULL ;
ChainConfig.cAdditionalStore=0 ;
ChainConfig.rghAdditionalStore = NULL ;
ChainConfig.dwFlags = CERT_CHAIN_CACHE_END_CERT;
ChainConfig.dwUrlRetrievalTimeout= 0 ;
ChainConfig.MaximumCachedCertificates=0 ;
ChainConfig.CycleDetectionModulus = 0;
```

CertCreateCertificateChainEngine function has the following signature:

```
BOOL WINAPI CertCreateCertificateChainEngine(
  _In_  PCERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG pConfig,
  _Out_ HCERTCHAINENGINE          *phChainEngine
);
```

And here is the debug screenshot of ChainConfig:

[image: ChainConfig]

hChainEngine is shown as NULL e.g. 0x00000000

Answer (score 1):

I figured the cause of this exception. The problem was that due to changes have been made after windows 7 we should initialize hExclusivrTrustPeople and hExclusiveRoot members too. So the mentioned article is sort of outdated for newer windows systems